# ArrayList<Objects[]> to strings to use in SQL IN statement

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, sql-in

I am trying to build a string to pass it as an SQL query within the IN statement.

```
ArrayList<Object[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(arrayList .size());
    for (Object object : arrayList ) {
        strings.add(Objects.toString(object, null));
    }

    System.out.println("askldnlkasdn"+strings);
```

This still prints out the memory locations instead of the actual string

```
askldnlkasdn[[Ljava.lang.Object;@7bb11784, [Ljava.lang.Object;@33a10788, [Ljava.lang.Object;@7006c658, [Ljava.lang.Object;@34033bd0, [Ljava.lang.Object;@47fd17e3, [Ljava.lang.Object;@7cdbc5d3, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3aa9e816, [Ljava.lang.Object;@17d99928, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3834d63f, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1ae369b7]
```

I have also tried out
using StringBuilder  and StringUtils. But things dont seem to work.

Any inputs as to where the problem is?

Comment: The code you posted is incorrect. The `ArrayList` is of `Object[]`, yet when you iterate it, it changes into just `Object`. I assume is a typo?

Comment: What is the actual type of underlying Object? You may override toString() method in appropriate class to make it work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is new code that may help,

```
// Data of Array of Object for test the Code
    Object[] a = new Object[1];
    a[0] = "Hello";
    Object[] b = new Object[1];
    b[0] = "Friend";
    Object[] c = new Object[1];
    c[0] = "This is";
    Object[] d = new Object[1];
    d[0] = "Just Test";

    // The Array List of objects and the data entry
    ArrayList<Object[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    arrayList.add(a);
    arrayList.add(b);
    arrayList.add(c);
    arrayList.add(d);

    // New List of strings
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(arrayList .size());


    // The Process of adding the data from array list of objects to the strings
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        strings.add((String) arrayList.get(i)[0]);
    }

    // Just for print the data to console
    for(int i = 0 ; i < strings.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(strings.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("askldnlkasdn "+strings.get(0));
```

I hope that solve the problem, if not please inform me, you can use it for more than one **dimensional array**.

Comment: I had thought of looping through the arrayList before. But, was looking for some alternative solutions before. I tried many solutions as proposed by others. I have finally used the looping method  to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should override method toString in your objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use an SQL specific java [`Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])).

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("... IN (?) ...")) {
    Object[] elements = ...
    stmt.setArray(1, connection.createArray("TEXT", elements));
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are implicitly using the `toString()` method of the `Object` elements inside your `ArrayList`. By default, that method returns the class and address of the `Object`. You should override the `toString()` method in every class you will use inside the list so it returns what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can just save it as `String` , like this code

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(arrayList .size());
    for (Object object : arrayList ) {
        strings.add(Objects.toString(object, null));
    }

    System.out.println("askldnlkasdn"+strings);
```

Or you want it Object for specific purpose?

Comment: Yes, the use of object was for some specific purpose.

Comment: Ok, i will post my new answare